# How to update periodically from service to activity in Android

Tags: android, service

I have somewhat experience with Android.I would like to know how to update periodically from service to activity in Android.I am playing with an app which has Location Service running at the background  and update to Activity how much the user is traveling. In the past, I broadcast distance from service and I use broadcast Receiver in Activity. However, this method is way too slow.

I recently discover that I can bind service, or use Handler to update periodically to activity from service. However, I do not understand detail especially Handler. Can anyone explain me how can I update periodically from service to activity using Handler. When I use handler, do I need to bind service? Or are those separate thing.

What I want is I want to update how much user travel by using onlocationChange() method from service to activity which has UI.

Answer (score 1):

I will first explain you how the onLocationChange(Location l) method works.

This method is call-back - it means it will be called by the android system automatically. It will be called A) after amount of time passes or B ) after your position changes by certain meters. Those two parameters are specified by you when you create the LocationManager.

Having this in mind, you should for example declare a global variable with the distance, lets say

> int a = 0;

Now in this method you must use the Location l which you are passed. You must add the moved distance to the variable a. Now, if all this code is inside the activity where you display the distance traveled, you simply use the variable a, else you have many choices. Either put it in shared preferences, or use function that sends that to the other activity.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, My app is already working with location part and I am using sendBoradcast() method inside onLocationChange(). I used broadcastReceiver in activity. The app is working except, it is delay in updating UI. Someone suggest me to use Binder or Handler. I look into those topics, is there a way I can use handler to send from service to activity. When I use handler, do I need to bind service and activity?

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at the official solution?
http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

also this is a good example for what you want
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll

I think this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First create one Interface to Update the location

Interface to get continuous updates.

```
public interface ILocationlistener {
 public void updateLocation(Location location);
 public void updateLatitude(Double lat);
 public void updateLongitude(Double lang);
}
```

update the ILocationlistener  interface in onLocationChanged(Location location) in LocationListener so every location changes you will get the updatats.

After Use ILocationListerner interfase to update location changes in Activity or Service. After getting location use Handler or UI thread to update the UI in main thread.

For example http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/03/get-location-and-its-changes-in-android.html?m=1